# From naudio.Wave.WaveIn to Stream ?

Tags: c#, stream, audio-recording, naudio

I copied this code and i don't understand it but i know what it does when it's finished (output -- sourceStream) ...

```
 NAudio.Wave.WaveIn sourceStream = null;
 NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut waveOut = null;
  NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter waveWriter = null;

        sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
    sourceStream.DeviceNumber = 2;
    sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(2).Channels);

    NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(sourceStream);

    waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
    waveOut.Init(waveIn);
    //sourceStream.DataAvailable.
    sourceStream.StartRecording();
    waveOut.Play();
    sourceStream.StopRecording();
```

What I know that this code records sound from a selected microphone and it gives an output for it (sourceStream)

So the first thing I need is -- > How can i get a stream out from this code (Like instead of WaveIn a Stream [Convert from WaveIn to Stream]) ?

And can you guys please Explain the code ... I tried the NAudio website for the explanation but i didn't understand --> I'm a beginner for audio and Streams...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the `DataAvailable` `event` provided by `WaveIn`, something like this

```
//Initialization of the event handler for event DataAvailable
sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);
```

And provide the `event handler`, the data that you need is in the `WaveInEventArgs` input argument of the `event handler`. Note that the data type of the audio is `short` so I would normally do like this,

```
private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e) {
  if (sourceStream == null)
    return;
  try {
    short[] audioData = new short[e.Buffer.Length / 2]; //this is your data! by default is in the short format
    Buffer.BlockCopy(e.Buffer, 0, audioData, 0, e.Buffer.Length);
    float[] audioFloat = Array.ConvertAll(audioData, x => (float)x); //I typically like to convert it to float for graphical purpose
    //Do something with audioData (short) or audioFloat (float)          
  } catch (Exception exc) { //if some happens along the way...
  }
}
```

However, if you want to convert get it in the `byte[]` format, then you should simply use `e.Buffer` directly or copying it to some short of `byte[]` whichever is more appropriate. As for me copying to `byte[]` array and then process it somewhere else is often more appropriate because the `WaveIn` stream is alive.

```
byte[] bytes = new short[e.Buffer.Length]; //your local byte[]
byteList.AddRange(bytes); //your global var, to be processed by timer or some other methods, I prefer to use List or Queue of byte[] Array
```

Then to convert your `byteList` to `Stream`, you can simply use `MemoryStream` with input of `byte[]`

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteList.ToArray()); //here is your stream!
```

Comment: Thanks for the response you have helped a lot :D

Comment: Glad to know that. ;)